# How to Unwarp UV to a complex model

Tags: uv

I'm a beginner at blender and I try to make a female character, but when I try to add some texture paint and adding hair for my character. It said missing UV, but I don't know how to Unwarp this character. Do I need to redo some parts of the process or missing some processes?[image]

Comment: hello, it has nothing to do with your question but are you sure that you need such a dense mesh?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the mesh
2. Go into *Edit Mode*
3. Press  <kbd>U</kbd>
4. Press *Smart UV Unwrap*

This should uv unwrap the mesh for you.

Comment: Thank a lot. It help me so much.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).